# Renaming Files In Python using time and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, operating-system

I want to rename some of my files using python.

The script should sort all files using date and add 1,2,3,... before actual file names.
Actual file name should not be changed.

Comment: Please add more details. What "date"? Date of creation? Date of last change? Date in filename? Date in first line of file? What do you mean by "add 1, 2, 3... before ... faile names" while "file name should not be changed"? What have you tried that isn't doing what you thought it would?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from os import listdir, rename
from os.path import getmtime
path = 'your_path'
filesName = listdir(path)
filesName.sort(key=lambda fileName: getmtime(path + fileName))
i=1
for fileName in filesName:
    rename(path + fileName, path + str(i) + fileName)
    i +=1
```